# Listbox is Completely Blank

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to populate a listbox from an array that I have. The listbox is getting the correct number of rows, but they're all blank. At first it wasn't even doing that, but I transposed my array and then at least it used the correct number of rows. Anybody have any ideas?

```
Public strArray() As String

lngArraySize = -1
ReDim strArray(1, 0)
For i = intLRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "E").Value - Cells(i, "D").Value = 0 Then
        lngArraySize = lngArraySize + 1
        ReDim Preserve strArray(1, lngArraySize)
        strArray(0, lngArraySize) = Format(Cells(i, "C").Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")
        strArray(1, lngArraySize) = Cells(i, "B").Value
    End If
Next i
```

Then I bring up the userform and populate it on initialize like this:

```
With .lstOptions
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100" 
    .List = Application.Transpose(strArray)
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that I can think of is that your range objects are not fully qualified and hence your code might be referring to the wrong sheet. If the code is referring to a blank worksheet then `E-D` will be `0` and hence the rows count is still what you are expecting. Change your code to this.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

'~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

intLRow = 5
lngArraySize = -1
ReDim strArray(1, 0)
For i = intLRow To 2 Step -1
    With ws
        If .Cells(i, "E").Value - .Cells(i, "D").Value = 0 Then
            lngArraySize = lngArraySize + 1
            ReDim Preserve strArray(1, lngArraySize)
            strArray(0, lngArraySize) = Format(.Cells(i, "C").Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")
            strArray(1, lngArraySize) = .Cells(i, "B").Value
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Sorry, I see you answered this just ahead of me, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout I dont have it with me right now, but I'll be able to check it in the morning. Thanks!